# unbuffered urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, buffering, urlopen

I have client for web interface to long running process. I'd like to have output from that process to be displayed as it comes. Works great with `urllib.urlopen()`, but it doesn't have `timeout` parameter. On the other hand with `urllib2.urlopen()` the output is buffered. Is there a easy way to disable that buffer?

Comment: Very similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: well, urlopen() returns object with file-like interface, but it's not a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick hack that has occurred to me is to use `urllib.urlopen()` with `threading.Timer()` to emulate timeout. But that's only quick and dirty hack.

Answer (score 0):

`urllib2` is buffered when you just call `read()`

you could define a size to read and therefore disable buffering.

for example:

```
import urllib2

CHUNKSIZE = 80

r = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org')
while True:
    chunk = r.read(CHUNKSIZE)
    if not chunk:
        break
    print(chunk)
```

this would print the response after each chunk is read from the socket, not buffer until the entire response is received.